# Remove lines containing ? from TextArea/String?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, search, text

Quick question here.

I want to search a TextArea component (flex) to see if there are any lines containing "?". If there is, the whole line will be removed.

How do I do this?

Example:
This is what I have:

```
10005 20003
10067 52234
03357 ?
30057 21135
64227 ? 
25777 99523
```

This is what I need to get:

```
10005 20003
10067 52234
30057 21135
25777 99523
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply loop through the lines and skip those that include a question mark. Something like that should work:

```
var newText = "";
var lines:Array = yourText.split("\n"); // or \r
for (var i:int = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var line:String = lines[i];
    if (line.indexOf("?") >= 0) continue;
    newText += line + "\n";
}

trace(newText);
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer! =)
This looks like it could work, but how do I do this with a TextArea component in flex?

Answer (score 1):

Use the regular expressions :

```
myTextArea.text = myTextArea.text.replace(/.*\?.*/g,"");
```

Comment: This doesnt remove the lines where the text was located on, but it's a quick and easy way to do it otherwise! Thanks :)
I didn't look for replace under the .text., only under myTextArea.*

Answer (score 0):

Should you want to get rid of the loop, this is the RegEx to use:

```
myTextArea.text = myTextArea.text.replace(/(^|\n|\r)+.*?\?.*/g,"");
```